# AJAX request causing Text.splitText to throw an error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, web-frontend

I am writing a javascript webpage, and in it, I am trying to send this Ajax request.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= title %></title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">     </script>
    <script>
     function onSubmit() {
      $.ajax({
        url: window.location.href,
        method: "POST",
        context: document.body,
        data: {newContent: $("#verseContent").contents()[0]},
        success: () => {console.log("DONE")},
        error: (err) => {console.error(err);}
      });
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <textarea id="verseContent"><%= content %></textarea>
    <button onClick="onSubmit()">SAVE</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

But it is always throwing the error:

```
[Error] TypeError: Can only call Text.splitText on instances of Text
    splitText (jquery.min.js:2:71316)
    i (jquery.min.js:2:71316)
    jt (jquery.min.js:2:71208)
    jt (jquery.min.js:2:71232)
    param (jquery.min.js:2:71508)
    ajax (jquery.min.js:2:75809)
    onSubmit (1:10)
    onclick (1:30)
```

I cannot seem to find any information to help debug this issue... Does anyone have any idea what might be going on? Thank you so much for any thoughts, ideas or any direction you may have.

Comment: What line does that error point to? We will need to see it. But apparently somewhere in your code you are calling (or some library is calling) `splitText` on something that is not a Text node

Comment: Looking at the code you are providing one can easily say there is nothing wrong with it, with the right data and the right controler that code works, Please follow stackoverflow guidelines https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve so we can help you out!

Comment: The error doesn't seem to be coming from the part of the code that you've shown in the question

Comment: Thank you all so much! I really appreciate you all looking it over. I have edited the question to show the full page as well as the full stack trace. The split text error is coming from within Jquery itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your AJAX request you should send `data` is JSON object.

In your situation, I guess that you want to send content from `textarea`. If true you can try this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title><%= title %></title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">     </script>
    <script>
        function onSubmit() {
        $.ajax({
            url: window.location.href,
            method: "POST",
            data: {
                newContent: $("#verseContent").text()
            },
            success: () => {console.log("DONE")},
            error: (err) => {console.error(err);}
        });
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<textarea id="verseContent"><%= content %></textarea>
<button onClick="onSubmit()">SAVE</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That was exactly what I needed!